# How to know that activity parameter belongs to which Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose I have a class A and contains a method which needs and activity and an int as parameters:

```
class A {
public void performActions(Activity activity, int a){
.....}
}
```

Now the following activities are accessing method performActions() in class A:

```
class B extends Activity{
    public void aMethod(){
    new class A().performActions(B.this, 1);
   }
}

class C extends Activity{
    public void aMethod(){
    new class A().performActions(C.this, 2);
   }
}
```

The question is:

> Is there a way that performActions() method in class A know that the activity parameter came from which activity and get back to that activity when it done its actions?

Comment: Pass a custom class object which contains name of class and Context  for starting Activity after action done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can keep a check like this

```
public void performActions(Activity activity, int a){

     if(activity instanceOf B){
         //came from B
     }

     if(activity instanceOf C){
         //came from C
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are meaning.
However,
I would think that you may want to provide a method that B,C overrides from Activity class, that returns which class it is (B or C). 
Otherwise consider adding names to activities through some method in Activity.

You don't provide much information about the use case of this code, so it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just i want to know that the activity parameter in class A came from which activity B or C?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`instanceOf`** to know  that context belong to which activity.

Here is the below code for the same

```
   if (context instanceof ActivityA) {

    } else {

    if (context instanceof ActivityB) {

    }    
   }
```